# Redirect web site request to a specific server in the farm with ARR

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, iis-7.5, arr

i currently use ARR (Application request routing) with a server farms of two server. My ARR is not currently setup with Host name affinity, but i would like to create a rewrite rule to redirect a specific web site request to a specific server in my web farm.

Is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  When the ARR Server Farm is setup you can say 'yes' to create a new rule for you automatically, but then immediately rename the rule so that ARR doesn't continue to handle it.  Otherwise if you make changes and later make a rule related change in ARR, it will blow away your tweaks.

Two good rules to use are {HTTP_HOST} for the domain name and {SERVER_ADDR} for the IP address.  You can add conditions to the rules to catch only specific traffic.

I've put together a few blog and video blog posts on URL Rewrite that you may find useful: http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/tags/URL+Rewrite/default.aspx.  I haven't covered ARR+URL Rewrite yet, but they'll be coming soon too.